# NullReferenceException when accessing a property outside of the constructor

Tags: c#, properties, constructor, nullreferenceexception

In this class, I am setting `elp` to `ElType` in the constructor.

I can access properties of `elp` fine when in the constructor (the `// ...` bit is where I'm accessing `elp`'s properties), but when I try to access `elp` in another method - `ucp()` - my program crashes with `NullReferenceException`.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here, although it would probably be something pretty straight forward.

```
[Serializable]
public class ElBase : RectangleNode
{
    public ElementParameters elp;

    public ElBase(ElementParameters ElType)
    {
        this.elp = ElType;

        // ...
    }

    private void ucp()
    {
        int i = 0;

        if (this.elp.HasInput)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the posted code. Please post more. Try to create a short, but complete, program that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Either:

1. `elp` is set to null, possibly even in the constructor if there's not a null check there
2. The `HasInput` property getter is throwing the `NullReferenceException` based on code inside it.
3. **Oh dear**: `elp` is a *publicly accessible field*. Anything can set it to null. :o This should be number 1, but I looked straight past it since no one makes publicly accessible fields, hence it's never a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say much without viewing the calling code but looks like `ElementParameters` passed to constructor was either NULL or not initialized.